# what is the execution sequence between route and component in Vue

Tags: web, frontend, components, vue-router, lifecycle

i am working in Vue application. I donnt know the execution sequence between route and component in Vue,especially, the lifecycle in two aspect. Such as beforeRoute, afterRoute, created, mount etc.
thanks a lot

the detail of the execution sequence between route and component in Vue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Precedence in lifecycle hooks with Vue.js and Vue-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405588/precedence-in-lifecycle-hooks-with-vue-js-and-vue-router)

Comment: thank your advice, and this link:   Precedence in lifecycle hooks with Vue.js and Vue-router  is not good for me ， i wan to kown thue mutation connection between vue-route and componet lifycycle